# Proving there are uncountably many continuous functions on an interval

Tags: elementary-set-theory

How can I prove that the set of real-valued continuous functions on a non-degenerate interval $[a,b]$ is uncountable? Can I use cardinality?

Comment: There's at least as many real valued continuous functions as there are constant functions.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** What is the simplest function you can think of?

Comment: of course,constant functions

Answer (score 2):

Since the question is about the cardinality of some set, you will certainly have to use cardinality in some way. HINT: Constant functions are continuous.

Comment: Yes,constant functions are continuous and on [a,b] each number corresponds one of constant function.but,I dont have another idea.

Comment: @EdaYıldız: You don’t need another idea: that’s already enough to answer the question.

Comment: namely,this is enough to proof.Thank you so much.

Comment: @EdaYıldız: Yes, it is. You’re welcome.